# partial view ASP MVC 5 C#: how to get part of the table using partial view?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make a table using partial view from another view.

the content of the view I want to desplay:

```
@model Agro1.ModelView.MessageViewModel
@using Agro1.Models


<span style="color:darkgreen">Messages</span>
<br />
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Subject</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Farmer Email</td>
    </tr>
    @{
        foreach (Message obj in Model.messages)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@obj.Subject</td>
                <td>@obj.Content</td>
                <td>@obj.FarmerEmail</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

in another view I want to desplay only the 5 first rows of this table.

now my code in the view looks like this:

```
@Html.Partial("DisplyaMessages",Model)
```

and it shows the full table.
how can I desplay only the 5 first rows?

t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use linq syntax .take(5) either in the controller action or in the razor.

Your razor code would look like this:

```
@{
    foreach (Message obj in Model.messages.take(5))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@obj.Subject</td>
            <td>@obj.Content</td>
            <td>@obj.FarmerEmail</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: The take method is executes in every iteration of foreach. wouldn't it be better if you first take the five record and store the result in somewhere then iterate through result?

Comment: thank you for the answer. How do I use the linq syntax? when I'm adding the .take(5), it marked as error.

Comment: do you mean that I should create new view with a table that contain only the first five rows?

Comment: Sorry to hear you an error in your code in writing .take(5)
Here's a link to the relevant Microsoft documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx
In answer to your second question, no you won't need to create a table that only has 5 rows. The intention is that .take(5) will select up to 5 rows from your table regardless of how many rows of data your table contains.  
You may have more success executing the code on the controller and using that to ensure the MessageViewModel is limited to 5 rows.

Comment: Hi Jason.  Thanks for your comment. I respectfully disagree that using the foreach causes the .take(5) to execute each iteration.  My understanding is that the .take operates similar to a where clause and that is certainly not going to be executed each iteration.  I would be interested to know why you think it would execute each iteration

Comment: Hi Tom and Jason, it worked!!! thank you very much for your help, it seems that I did something wrong before. :)

Comment: Hi Daria.  Well done and you're very welcome. Thanks for letting us know it worked.   :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new property into the model with the max rows to display.
After that you can check this property during the foreach.

```
@model Agro1.ModelView.MessageViewModel
@using Agro1.Models


<span style="color:darkgreen">Messages</span>
<br />
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Subject</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Farmer Email</td>
    </tr>
    @{
        var x = 0;
        foreach (Message obj in Model.messages)
        {
            if (Model.MaxRows > 0 && x > Model.MaxRows) break;
            <tr>
                <td>@obj.Subject</td>
                <td>@obj.Content</td>
                <td>@obj.FarmerEmail</td>
            </tr>
            x++;
        }
    }
</table>
```

You can call the partial creating a new model like this:

```
@Html.Partial("DisplyaMessages", new MessageViewModel { MaxRows = 5, messages = Model.messages})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. it is not recognizing the MaxRows expression

Comment: Did you add the property MaxRows into the MessageViewModel model?

Comment: In this way you can use the same partial in all the views, just setting the max rows